# Why do I get error of cannot find symbol of class URLDecoder?

Tags: java

First and foremost, these are information about my Java environment:

- `java version "1.8.0_60"`
- `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)`
- `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`

In my project, I wrote these 2 lines:

```
URLDecoder tehee = new URLDecoder();
String programPath = tehee.decode(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "UTF-8");
```

Note: I make `import java.lang.*;`

However, I got these errors:

> MyClass.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
>   **U**RLDecoder tehee = new **U**RLDecoder();

It pinpointed **URLDecoder**. (my assumption: as if there are no **URLDecoder** class within **java.lang.***)

**Why do I get error of cannot find symbol of class URLDecoder?**

Comment: Well, it's not in `java.lang`. It's in `java.net`.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, it should tell you if the class is under lang or not once you start typing it name.

Comment: URLDecoder.decode is a static method.  Constructing an instance of URLDecoder accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: *bulb-light-sounds My problem solved thanks to @RealSkeptic comments - I repeat for him "_it's not in java.lang. It's in java.net_". Please write it as answer, I will mark it!